# How to connect SPSS to a DB2 database

Tags: db2, odbc, spss, spss-modeler

I want to connect my SPSS Modeler 16.0 to my database IBM DB2. I tried to add the server by doing this: Tools>Server login>Add. I added the properties (IP address and port). Now when I select the server and type the userID and password and press OK I get a connection fail. 
I'm running a French version and this is the translated error that I get :

```
Connection to server failed db2admin@localhost:50001
Server exception : please check the server connection status
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you connect to the database from the DB2 command line processor? How did you check that the DB2 instance is running?

Comment: Yes I can. I even tried to connect to the database with a client "Squirrel SQL client" and it worked

Comment: Well, if you can connect with other application, the problem appears to be in SPSS or its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting on port 50001 which is the SSL port for db2, since it's a local database, you might try port 50000 which is unencrypted...